# Maven to create linux suitable build in windows OS

Tags: linux, windows, maven

My development environment is windows. When I package a jar in my maven project, the variable {user.home} is being replaced with the appropriate windows path (C:\users\MyUsername\).
Then, before I distribute the jar to my linux server, I manually change the path to the linux equivalent. 
Is there a way to force maven to build the jar suitable to linux deployment while I'm working on windows OS?

Comment: Where exactly do you need `user.home`?

Comment: So when you need the `user.home` during runtime, why do you resolve the value during the build? Why don't you resolve it during runtime?